# Where to specify custom directive dependency. is it the same at controller and directive level?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive defined like this:

```
app.directive('tagProfile', ['userService', function(userService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            mode: '@'
            ,entity: '='
            ,onUpdate: '&'
            ,onCancel: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: '/public/user/tag_profile.html',

        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.userService = userService
        }],

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    }
}])
```

Notice that I inject `userService` in `directive`, because most of tutorials on custom directive inject dependencies there. I have tried to inject it in controller function and it works as well

```
    controller: ['$scope', 'userService', function($scope, userService)
```

I am most likely to use only controller function, not link function. so userService won't be used in link. Beside that, is injecting in both places the same? or which one is better?

Also, why is the link function injects `scope` instead of `$scope`? and we dont use explicit annotation for minify support?

Comment: you can name scope $scope if you want to.

Comment: @Chillewoodz but why do we use `scope` in almost all tutorials including the official one? what about DI annotation string?

Comment: I really don't know why, seems odd to me as well. Maybe it's to separate it somehow.

Comment: the link function is called with a `scope` provided as a parameter, it doesn't need a `$scope` object passed in as a dependency.  the common convention of using `scope` rather than `$scope` is based on the fact that in one case, you are using the `$scope` class defined by angular, in the other you are using an *instance* of `scope` provided by the caller.

Comment: In link function parameters and their order are predefined and fixed: the first one is always `scope`, then `element`, etc. You can't swap them - they are not injected by name as in controller function.

Comment: @scope so minifying it will not break my code since it's not using DI?

Comment: @OMGPOP - Minifying should not break anything in the case you have supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am most likely to use only controller function, not link function. so userService won't be used in link. Beside that, is injecting in both places the same? or which one is better?

If you're not going to utilise the link step, stick to injecting into the `controller`. If you wanted to utilise the controller and the link step, go for injection at the directive definition.

There is no difference in `which of the two is better` or `which of the two is recommended` as far as I know.

This is referring to the `userService` in this case. Injecting `$scope` into the directive definition, is not something I've ever done so I can't say what sort of side effects that may bring.

Is it the same?

- *From the controllers point of view? Yes.*
- *From the linkers point of view? No.*

---

> Also, why is the link function injects scope instead of $scope? and we dont use explicit annotation for minify support?

The first parameter to `link` will always be a `$scope`, so it doesn't matter what you name it.

```
/** 
 * $compileProvider.$get
 * L#6931 in angular.js 
 */
return compile;

function compile($compileNodes, transcludeFn, maxPriority, ignoreDirective, previousCompileContext) {
  /**
   * Redacted code...
   */
  return function publicLinkFn(scope, cloneConnectFn, options) {
```

Explicit annotation is not needed for the link function (returned by `compile`) as it is not prone(or, open) to DI. It's arguments are pre-set.

This would work just as well as being explicit in the naming:

```
return {
  link: function (a,b,c) {
    // { a: $scope, b: $element, c: $attrs }
  }
}
```

---

**tl;dr**

- Dont inject 'stuff' into the `directive` if you're only using 'stuff' in the `controller`.
- `link` is not open to DI.